# how to convert am/ pm symbols to current localization in swift / IOS

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdateformatter

I have a requirement for converting am/pm symbol format to respective locale. here is code snippet

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "h:mm aa"
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
return formatter
```

even i tried changing code to his but couldn't succeed.

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
let locale = Locale.autoupdatingCurrent
formatter.locale = locale
```

and also using the locale identifier

```
let locale = Locale(identifier: "de-DE")
formatter.locale = locale
```

But no luck, please provide valuable inputs on the same and very thankful in advance.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve. Could you add an example with input and expected result?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear what you're trying to do. You defined a DateFormatter that will convert `Date` objects to/from time strings that contain AM/PM. If you want to take a Date string that contains time with an AM/PM suffix and convert it to 24-hour time, you either need 2 separate `DateFormatter`s, or you need to change their format strings between conversions.

Consider this Mac playground code:

```
import Cocoa

let  formatterWithAmPM: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm aa"
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
    return formatter
}()

let formatterWith24HourTime: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
    return formatter
}()


let startingDateString = "06/15/2021 02:26 PM"
if let date = formatterWithAmPM.date(from: startingDateString) {
    print("Date string '\(startingDateString) in 24 hour time = '\(formatterWith24HourTime.string(from:date))'")
}
```

That outputs:

```
Date string '06/15/2021 02:26 PM in 24 hour time = '06/15/2021 14:26'
```

(I added month/day/year to my date format so I could specify a full date and time. A time without a date is incomplete.)

Comment: convert am and pm to respective locale. for example 7.30 pm  to 7.30 Uhr in german

Comment: there are these symbols that can be changed: formatter.amSymbol = "Uhr morgens" and formatter.pmSymbol = "Uhr".